# Python BeautifulSoup - how to extract text between <a> tags

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

i want to extract a number "371" from this source with BeautifulSoup4 in Python3.
I tried many times but i can not make it work, could You help me? Thank You.

```
<a href="/ProviderRedirect.ashx?key=0.16198127.422314246.13.PLN.1277906077&amp;saving=551&amp;source=1-0" id="TotalLink" target="_blank"><span class="hc_pr_cur">PLN</span> 371<span class="hc_pr_syb"></span></a>
```

Comment: What have you tried? Showing your attempts will provide context and make it clear if you are having trouble excluding the span element, or if you aren't getting the inner HTML of the a element.

Comment: For example this does not work: `soup.find_all("a", id="TotalLink")` This also does not work: `soup.find("span", {"class": "hc_pr_cur"})`

Comment: The phrase "does not work" summarizes the situation, but saying what result it returned is more helpful. "When I tried `soup.find_all("a", id="TotalLink")` it returned ..."

Comment: It always return "None"

Comment: might be better to supply the link if possible

Comment: It is: `http://www.hotelscombined.com/Hotel/Search?resultID=0&checkin=2015-01-01&checkout=2015-01-02&Rooms=1&adults_1=2&languageCode=PL&currencyCode=PLN&fileName=Blow_Up_Hall_5050`

Comment: you would have to enter data into the boxes, I think something like selenium would be a better option.

Comment: I do not understand, what boxes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the `span` tag and get the [`.next_sibling`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#next-sibling-and-previous-sibling):

```
soup.find('span', class_='hc_pr_cur').next_sibling.strip()
```

Demo:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>>
>>> data = '<a href="/ProviderRedirect.ashx?key=0.16198127.422314246.13.PLN.1277906077&amp;saving=551&amp;source=1-0" id="TotalLink" target="_blank"><span class="hc_pr_cur">PLN</span> 371<span class="hc_pr_syb"></span></a>'
>>>
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
>>> soup.find('span', class_='hc_pr_cur').next_sibling.strip()
u'371'
```

Comment: I tried this and error show up: `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'next_sibling'
`

Comment: @Mateusz can be multiple reasons for that: the HTML you see in the browser in not the same you are passing into `BeautifulSoup` - so there is really no `span` with `class="hc_pr_cur"` element. Or, this might indicate the differences between underlying parser that `BeautifulSoup` uses - in this case you may try to explicitly specify the parser, e.g. `soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')`. Or, could be an another reason - difficult to say without seeing the complete code you have at the moment.

Comment: @Mateusz besides, as you see from the answer - it is working with the data and information you've provided.

Comment: Yes, i also think it does not work because BeautifulSoup does not load website in good way. Here is this site: `http://www.hotelscombined.com/Hotel/Search?resultID=0&checkin=2015-01-01&checkout=2015-01-02&Rooms=1&adults_1=2&languageCode=PL&currencyCode=PLN&fileName=Blow_Up_Hall_5050` I do not know how to make it work, could You help me?

Comment: @Mateusz, it's **not** BeautifulSoup's job to "load websites" -- it's to interpret HTML!-)  You need to do the "load website" job previously.  Using `curl` from the command line you can see the URL you gives has a redirect, which in turn has another redirect, which sends you to `http://www.hotelscombined.pl/` -- which has a lot of Javascript presumably to retrieve the answer.  Maybe try Selenium or the like if you're keen to defeat the measures they're taking against just the kind of scraping you appear to be bent on doing!